# How to lookup multiple times and average them in excel

Tags: excel, time, average, vlookup, countif

I have a workbook where the first page gives stats and the second page has raw data. I am trying to write a lookup function where it will add all of the times for a specific person (taken from say A2 on sheet 1) on

I want the sheet to lookup the value in a2 on sheet1 in sheet 2 and take the average of all of the times from column H that match the lookup value in A2!sheet1.

I'm not sure if it is so I'm happy to answer clarification questions if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Are you matching Sheet1!A2 to a specific column? If so then try `AVERAGEIF` function, e.g. assuming names are in column B on sheet 2 try

`=AVERAGEIF(Sheet2!B:B,A2,Sheet2!H:H)`

Comment: Ok, so based on your advice I came up with the following: =AVERAGEIF(Raw.A1:H250;A2;Raw.A2:H250) But now I'm getting a #div/0 error, I'm guessing that it's because of the second "Raw.a2:H250" causing a loop, is that right?